# How to back up database in server exp using Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I have connected database sql server Management  studio.I am trying to backup database I can't able to have backup. so connected server exp in visual stdio connected server database. 
How can back up full database or generate script using visual studio when server Exp connected ?

Answer (score 2):

Use This Query

```
BACKUP DATABASE DatabaseName TO DISK = 'C:\DatabaseName.bak'
```

Comment: Right click on Database on go to Task>>Generate Scripts>>Next  then set true option for which you required script it will generate for you.

Comment: am not able to generate script using  server database  thats why using sever exp in visual studio

Comment: In server Explorer Add **Data Connection** of your database using proper credential and after connection done you can fire query on the same.